Hrv frequency parameter fft-method unit question
I've been working on a function to detect the LF and HF of animal ECG. The final output unit should be milliseconds squared (ms²). However, I'm not sure if my conversions are correct. I found some papers indicating that the output values should be around 300-800. But the values I calculated are in the small decimal range. I'm not sure if this is due to an error in my unit conversion.
def detect_frequency_parameters(sig, fs):
    N = len(sig)
    freqs = np.fft.fftfreq(N, 1/fs)
    fft_vals = np.fft.fft(sig)
    
   
    pxx = np.abs(fft_vals)**2 / N
    
   
    pos_mask = freqs >= 0
    freqs = freqs[pos_mask]
    pxx = pxx[pos_mask]
    
   
    lf_indices = np.where((freqs >= 0.04) & (freqs < 0.15))[0]
    hf_indices = np.where((freqs >= 0.15) & (freqs < 0.4))[0]
    
   
    LF = simps(pxx[lf_indices], freqs[lf_indices])
    HF = simps(pxx[hf_indices], freqs[hf_indices])
    
    (ms*ms)
    TP = (LF + HF) * 1e6  # 1e6 = 1000 * 1000
    LF *= 1e6
    HF *= 1e6
    
    return {
        "TP": TP,
        "LF": LF,
        "HF": HF,
        "LF_HF_ratio": LF / HF if HF != 0 else np.inf,
    }

I would like to know if there is an error in my method. By the way, the input signal unit I am using is mV (millivolts).

I think your main question is already sort of answered here numpy fft vs fftfreq with an example. But I think from your units you are actually wanting the power spectrum which is the absolute magnitude of the raw FFT (rather than the raw values). I presume that "simps()" (code not provided) is a simple integration code.
